# Excel VBA Macro - Execute Formula using value of a cell in one location

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and was trying to write a macro for some calculations. 
One of the calculations involves reading in data from a particular location (R2C2 for example) and using a formula to compute a value stored in the adjacent column (R2C3 in this example).

I have this line: 
ActiveSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(row_number, Col + 1).Formula = "=ActiveSheet.Cells(row_number, Col).Value + 10"

But it does not seem to work and I am not sure why. Everything I have searched for uses Range but I am not sure how to use Range when I am referencing my cells using Row, Column notation instead of A1/B1 notations.

Any help would be great - Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason why this works:
Range(rng2).Cells.Formula = "=MROUND(TRUNC(C2,1),0.5)"
but not the code I had before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to make a formula:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(row_number, Col + 1).Formula = "=" & Cells(row_number, Col).Address & "+10"
```